# Reverse for 'date_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['date/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models and a third model for a many-to-many relationship
the form should take a date from the first model that is the date model and the user will choose images from the second model and connect them

but when I'm making the form I'm getting this error

Reverse for 'date_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['date/(?P[0-9]+)$']

my models.py

```
class MyDate(models.Model):
    english_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    hebrew_date = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    sof_zman_1 = models.TimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    sof_zman_2 = models.TimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    sof_zman_tefila = models.TimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True,null=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self ):
        return reverse('date_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hebrew_date

# images
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(unique=False,upload_to='images/')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("image_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

#connect days and images together
class DayImage(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('luach.MyDate',related_name='day',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ManyToManyField('luach.images',related_name='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

my views.py

```
def create_day_image_view(request,pk):
    date = get_object_or_404(MyDate,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DayImageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dayimage = form.save(commit=False)
            dayimage.date = date
            dayimage.save()
            return redirect('date_detail',pk=date.pk)
            
    else:
        form = DayImageForm()
    return render(request, 'luach/dayimage_form.html',{'form': form})
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('date/<int:pk>',views.MyDateDetailView.as_view(),name='date_detail'),
    path('date/<int:pk>/add_image/',views.create_day_image_view,name='add_image')
]
```

and my dayimage_form.html

```
{% block content %}
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>save</button>
            </form>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'date_detail' pk=date.pk %}">cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: Where exactly is `mydate` in `return redirect('date_detail',pk=mydate.pk)` created? I see a reference, but no assignment to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that this line causes the error

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'date_detail' pk=date.pk %}">
```

because I don't see anywhere that you pass the variable `date` to the template context, so it probably is `None`, which causes the error.

A solution could be to pass the variable to the context:

```
return render(
    request,
    'luach/dayimage_form.html',
    {
        'form': form,
        'date': date,
    })
```